# PDFBOX generates error on embedSubset option is true when loading Unicode font (e.g. Japanese)

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I load Japanese font, if I set true to embedSubset argument, it generates error. It set false, it works. However, the output file size became huge. So, I do not want to embed whole font.
How can I embed subset characters only to reduce file size ?
I can achieve this by iText, but I cannot use it due to license issue.

PDFBOX version: 2.0.30
=================

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+65E5 (日) in font TsukuhouMincho-Regular
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:389)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:427)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:337)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getStringWidth(PDFont.java:368)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.calculateFontSize(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:828)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.insertGeneratedAppearance(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:488)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceContent(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:424)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceValue(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:248)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:264)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:227)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:219)
at TEST_PDFBOX.testMSMincho(TEST_PDFBOX.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

=========================================================

```
PDDocument pdDoc;
            //For ver3.0.1
            //pdDoc = Loader.loadPDF(new File(pdffile));
            //For ver2.x.x
            pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdffile));

            //TsukuhouMincho is free Japanese font. If I set true to embedSubset argument, it generates error.

            PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdDoc, PDFBOXTester.class.getResourceAsStream("/font/TsukuhouMincho-Regular.ttf"), false);
            

            PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();
            PDTextField textfield = (PDTextField) pdAcroForm.getField("Text_TaxOffice_JP");

            PDResources res = pdAcroForm.getDefaultResources();
            String fontName = res.add(font).getName();
            textfield.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g");
            textfield.setValue(someJapanaeseStrings);
            
            pdDoc.save(new File(args[1]));
```

I tried several version of PDFBOX - 2.x.x or 3.x.x - none of them worked.

Comment: Does that glyph exist in that font or not?

Comment: I believe there should be as, if i load whole font (embedSubst = false), it works.

Comment: Please share the PDF and the font. However it's generally a bad idea to use subsetting in AcroForm. Because problems will occur when people start to edit such a field with a partial font.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.. i agree subsetting is not best option. however, japanese font size is quite huge (> 5MB). Actually there are Japanese fonts already installed in user's environment. Hence, embedding font is not technically required. is there any way to set Japanese without embedding font ? I know iText can do it since it has bundled Japanese fonts, but no idea how to do with PDFBOX, hence trying to subsetting way. I will share font and PDF file (if possible) later.

Comment: We discourage "not embedding fonts" by not having an API for that. You could remove the /FontFile2 COSStream through the COS API. (Use PDFDebugger to understand where to go)